# Как прилепить кнопочку к левой части сайта

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Здравствуйте, есть некая кнопка "Консультация" каким образом её можно прилепить к левой стороне сайта? Как например лепятся все онлайн консультанты. Необходимо сделать также. 
Скажите каким образом это возможно реализовать? Средствами jquery или только css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#block_id {
    position:fixed; 
    left: 0px;
 }
```